# Jenkins multijob plugin doesn't execute in parallel the same job on different nodes

Tags: jenkins

I configured in MultiJob plugin to have one phase, with the same job running on 2 different nodes.

e.g.

```
Download Files for Node LINUXVM
Download Files for Node WINDOWSVM
```

However, these jobs are not being run in parallel as you can see from the screen shot. the job itself waits for the previous one to finish although it's on different node

[image]

Is it possible to call the same jobs, but since it's on different nodes, that they will run in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set the inner job (Download...) to execute current builds if necessary

[image]